# JSF-2 Select/Unselect all the list of checkboxes with single checkbox

Tags: checkbox, richfaces, jsf-2.2

I have list of check boxes inside rich:dataTable and I want to check all the boxes at once with a single check box from header column.

```
<rich:column id="includeInWHMapping" >
      <f:facet name="header">
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{checkallbox.selectAll}">
           <f:ajax actionListener="#{checkallbox.selectAllBox}" render="selectedForWHProcess" />
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>  
      </f:facet>        
      <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="selectedForWHProcess" value="#{checkallbox.checked[data]}">      
         <f:ajax actionListener="#{checkallbox.selectAllRows}"/>
      </h:selectBooleanCheckbox></rich:column>
```

Code in checkallbox Bean:

```
private Map<StandardStructure, Boolean> checked = new HashMap<StandardStructure, Boolean>();        
private boolean selectAll;

public boolean isSelectAll() {
    return selectAll;
}

public void setSelectAll(boolean selectAll) {
    this.selectAll = selectAll;
}

public Map<StandardStructure, Boolean> getChecked() {
    return checked;
}

public void setChecked(Map<StandardStructure, Boolean> checked) {
    this.checked = checked;
}

public void selectAllBox(ValueChangeEvent e){
    boolean newSelectAll = (Boolean) e.getNewValue();
    Iterator<StandardStructure> keys = checked.keySet().iterator();
    while(keys.hasNext()){
        StandardStructure ss = keys.next();
        checked.put(ss, newSelectAll);
    }
}
```

When I check the h:selectBooleanCheckBox of header column nothing happens. What am I missing here? Should I have to implement Map for "selectAll" property too?

Thanks.

Comment: Is `selectAllBox` fired and did you try to render whole table?

Comment: @EmilSierżęga Yeah its fired but no such changes seen on the list of checkboxes. I did not render the whole table but the checkboxes column. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: You have to render whole table. You can't render just "a column". In rendered HTML there's no such a thing a column, so you wan't to render several `<TD>`'s with id like `tableId:_NUMBER_:selectedForWHProcess`. Read this two topics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706849/how-to-do-a-column-level-render-in-datatable-in-jsf and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16043218/refer-to-jsf-dynamically-generated-ids-based-on-iteration-index

Comment: @EmilSierżęga Hey thanks! But how shall I do that? I am new in JSF. Sorry! :)

Comment: And why don't you want to try rendering whole table?

Comment: @EmilSierżęga Actually I did render the Whole rich:dataTable with <f:ajax actionListener="#{checkallbox.selectAllBox}" render="dataTableID" />. But Nothing happens.

Comment: @BalusC Please help me!

Comment: Calling someone out like that is extremely rude! If someone wants to help you, he/she will. Now... I gave you working example in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all. `f:ajax` doesn't have `actionListener`, it has a `listener`. Read the docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/f/ajax.html). Second thing, you can use `valueChangeListener` on `h:selectBooleanCheckbox` and only there. Third, listener inside rows boxes is wrong. Basically, it looks like you need to read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener).

Now, here is the working example:

```
<h:form>
    <rich:dataTable value="#{checkallbox.allValues}" var="data" id="dataTable">
        <rich:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{checkallbox.selectAll}"
                    valueChangeListener="#{checkallbox.selectAllBox}">
                    <f:ajax render="dataTable" />
                </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
            </f:facet>
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{checkallbox.checked[data]}">
                <f:ajax />
            </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        </rich:column>

        <!-- other columns -->
    </rich:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Other possible problems with your code (since you've shared just a part).

- The data table needs to be in form, since you're executing ajax inside.
- Your keys in map are objects. You have to make sure that `equals` method is good. In 95% of case the default is not, especially if they are `@Entity`.
- You have to make sure that the map is populated with false at the beginning. I use `@PostConstruct`:

  ```
  @PostConstruct
  protected void performPostConstructAction() {
      for (StandardStructure s : getAllValues()) {
          checked.put(s, false);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks Emil! I really appreciate your effort. I did not use @PostConstruct. But now it works. The only problem now I have is while pagination all the checked boxes are unchecked but the rows are selected.

Comment: Glad I could help, but it looks like the problem is solved since you've marked your answer as accepted :-)

Comment: Actually I accepted your answer! I miss checked mine! :P Accepted your answer again! Thanks! : )

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Emil! I solved it.

```
public void selectAllBox(){
    if(!selectAll){
        for(StandardStructure item : ssTable.getDto()){
            checked.put(item, true);
        }
    }else{
        for(StandardStructure item : ssTable.getDto()){
            checked.put(item, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't an answer for your question, but as you wish.